.NETで作成した情報入力パレットでキーボード入力Ctrl＋Vをキャッチする方法が知りたい
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8を使用して、IJCAD 2023上で情報入力パレットを作成しました。
メモ帳やExcelに入力したテキストデータをコピーし、情報入力パレットのテキストボックスに貼り付けるとき、
右クリックから［貼り付け］は実行できます。
しかしキーボード入力のCtrl＋Vでの貼り付けは、アプリ画面でなくIJCAD作図画面上にテキストを貼り付ける動作になります。
GRX(C++)の参考記事をご紹介いただいたのですが、.NETで対応できる方法はないでしょうか？


キーボード入力のCtrl＋Vでの貼り付けは、アプリ画面でなくIJCAD作図画面上にテキストを貼り付ける動作になります。

試してみましたが、同様の挙動になりました。
IJCADでは、情報入力パレットのテキストボックスがアクティブな状態でも、
Ctrl＋Vが押されるとPASTECLIPコマンドが優先されていそうですね。

.NETで対応できる方法はないでしょうか？

CUIコマンドからPASTECLIPコマンドのショートカットキーを変更すれば、
目的としている"キーボード入力のCtrl＋Vでの貼り付け"が可能と考えられます。
PASTECLIPコマンドのショートカットキーの変更を避けたい場合、
Ctrl＋Vの代わりに、Shift+Insertを使う方法でもよいかもしれません。

ありがとうございます。ショートカットキーの編集を試してみます。
